# Login em Swift Autorização

Tags: api, swift, login, token

Estou consumindo dados de uma certa *API* para login, ela me retorna o `Token` de acesso correto, e caso ao contrário retorna o **ERRO**, porém não consigo fazer transitar para outra tela caso os campos estiverem preenchidos corretamente, segue o código da API abaixo:

```
let postString = "usuario=" + user + "&senha=" + _psw
    request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {
            print("error=\(String(describing: error))")
            self.alert(title: "Ops!", msg: "Login inválido.")
            return
        }

       // let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse
        if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {
            print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")

            }
        let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
        print("responseString = \(String(describing: responseString))")

        }
    task.resume()


}
```

Comment: Junior, não entendi o que você quis dizer com "não consigo transitar para outra tela...". Em que momento você gostaria de fazer essa transição?

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que entendi, você quer direcionar o usuário para outra tela caso o login seja bem sucedido.

Neste caso você pode apresentar a próxima tela como um modal:

```
if loginOK {
    present(yourNextViewController, animated: true)
}
```

Ou adicioná-la no topo do seu `navigationController`:

```
if loginOK {
    navigationController?.pushViewController(yourNextViewController, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: Lembrando que tem que ver se essa chamada de present/push está sendo chamada na Main Thread